# Non aligned lines in tabular

Tags: tables

In this table, the two parts of the last line are not aligned. Why and how to fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{} m{2cm} <{\hspace*{1mm}} | m{1.9cm} <{\hspace*{1mm}}}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor{black!20!white}{}}\\[-3mm]
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor{black!20!white}{\footnotesize $\ \mathbf{15}$ \hspace{0pt plus 1filll} Test}}\\[1.5mm]
\scriptsize \hfill $\times \hspace{-1pt}\approx\hspace{-1pt}\checked$
& \scriptsize \hfill $\times \hspace{-1pt}\approx\hspace{-1pt}\checked$  \\                                                          
\dotfill\scriptsize $\square$\,$\square$\,$\square$ & \dotfill\scriptsize $\square$\,$\square$\,$\square$\\
\dotfill\scriptsize $\square$\,$\square$\,$\square$ & \dotfill\scriptsize $\square$\,$\square$\,$\square$\\
\dotfill\scriptsize $\square$\,$\square$\,$\square$ & \dotfill\scriptsize $\square$\,$\square$\,$\square$\\[3mm]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Log

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017)
>   (preloaded format=pdflatex)  \write18 enabled. entering extended mode
>   (./bac_a_sable.tex LaTeX2e <2017-04-15> Babel <3.10> and hyphenation
>   patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
>   Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty)
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty))
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/colortbl/colortbl.sty))
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wasysym/wasysym.sty)
>   (./bac_a_sable.aux)
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
>   [Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).] )
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wasysym/uwasy.fd)
>   [1{/usr/local/t
>   exlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
>   (./bac_a_sable.aux) 
>   )<
>   /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
>   Output written on bac_a_sable.pdf (1 page, 42174 bytes). SyncTeX
>   written on bac_a_sable.synctex.gz. Transcript written on
>   bac_a_sable.log.

Comment: Are you sure you get that output, I can't reproduce this error?

Comment: Yes. I wil add the log.

Comment: Related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439669/issue-with-colored-cell-in-tabularx ?

Comment: I think the two issues are independent one from the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interaction between `m` columns and the `\\[..]` optional length argument was corrected in the 2018 `array` package release so with an up to date system you get better alignment. In general though using `m` especially in combination with `<{\hspace*{1mm}` is a rather fragile setting. (`m` columns are designed for multi-line paragraph boxes with line breaking within the cell, you do not have that here, and adding an `\hspace` just on the last line of a paragraph only does anything sensible as there is only one line here.

Comment: I've replaced `m{2cm}` by `p{2cm}` and it is solved.