# Issue with colored cell in tabular

Tags: tables, cellcolor

In the following, there is an issue in the colouring of the first line. It should be a one simple grey block but there is some overlaying white rectangle.

Why and how to fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{} m{2cm} <{\hspace*{1mm}} | m{1.9cm} <{\hspace*{1mm}}}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor{black!20!white}{}}\\[-3mm]
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor{black!20!white}{\footnotesize $\ \mathbf{15}$ \hspace{0pt plus 1filll} Test}}\\[1.5mm]
\scriptsize \hfill $\times \hspace{-1pt}\approx\hspace{-1pt}\checked$
& \scriptsize \hfill $\times \hspace{-1pt}\approx\hspace{-1pt}\checked$  \\                                                          
\dotfill\scriptsize $\square$\,$\square$\,$\square$ & \dotfill\scriptsize $\square$\,$\square$\,$\square$\\
\dotfill\scriptsize $\square$\,$\square$\,$\square$ & \dotfill\scriptsize $\square$\,$\square$\,$\square$\\
\dotfill\scriptsize $\square$\,$\square$\,$\square$ & \dotfill\scriptsize $\square$\,$\square$\,$\square$\\[3mm]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Log

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017)
>   (preloaded format=pdflatex)  \write18 enabled. entering extended mode
>   (./bac_a_sable.tex LaTeX2e <2017-04-15> Babel <3.10> and hyphenation
>   patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
>   Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty)
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty))
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty))
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/colortbl/colortbl.sty))
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wasysym/wasysym.sty)
>   (./bac_a_sable.aux)
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
>   [Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).] )
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
>   (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wasysym/uwasy.fd)
>   [1{/usr/local/t
>   exlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
>   (./bac_a_sable.aux) 
>   )<
>   /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
>   Output written on bac_a_sable.pdf (1 page, 42174 bytes). SyncTeX
>   written on bac_a_sable.synctex.gz. Transcript written on
>   bac_a_sable.log.

Comment: Related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439668/non-aligned-lines-in-tabular ?

Comment: I think the two issues are independent one from the other.

Comment: your title and tag mention `tabularx` but your example doesn't use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand well, what you are trying to achieve, it's much simpler to use a single row for the table head, and the `cellspace` package to increase the row height! The problem was using two `\multicolumn`s with different alignments, or hspace specifications. i.e., remove the '{0 plus 1fill}'. Possibly,  `\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor{black!20!white}{\footnotesize $\ \mathbf{15} $ \hspace{1.5mm} {\bf Test}}}\\`

See below, for a possible alternative/correction using the cellspace package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{8pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{8pt}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{} m{2cm} <{\hspace*{1mm}} | m{1.9cm} <{\hspace*{1mm}}}
\rowcolor{black!20!white}\multicolumn{1}{@{}Sl}{\footnotesize $\ \mathbf{15} $} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\footnotesize Test}\\
\scriptsize \hfill $\times \hspace{-1pt}\approx\hspace{-1pt}\checked$
& \scriptsize \hfill $\times \hspace{-1pt}\approx\hspace{-1pt}\checked$ \\
\dotfill\scriptsize $\square$\,$\square$\,$\square$ & \dotfill\scriptsize $\square$\,$\square$\,$\square$\\
\dotfill\scriptsize $\square$\,$\square$\,$\square$ & \dotfill\scriptsize $\square$\,$\square$\,$\square$\\
\dotfill\scriptsize $\square$\,$\square$\,$\square$ & \dotfill\scriptsize $\square$\,$\square$\,$\square$\\[3mm]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bernard. Where Can I find more info on `\multicolumn{1}{@{}Sl}` (esp. the `Sl`)?

Comment: The prefix `S`  defines a minimal vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefiexed with this letter. If you load `siunitx`, which defines an `S` column type, you have to use the letter `C`. You'll find some other details in the package documentation. On the other hand, `\multicolumn` here is also used to remove the vertical rule in the table header.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

{\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
 \newcommand\mcbf[2]{\multicolumn{1}{#1}{\normalsize\textbf{#2}}}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash\scriptsize}p{2cm} <{\hspace*{1mm}} | 
                        >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash\scriptsize}p{2cm} <{\hspace*{1mm}}}
\rowcolor{black!20!white}
\mcbf{l}{15}  &   \mcbf{r}{Test}              \\
$\times \hspace{-1pt}\approx\hspace{-1pt}\checked$
                    &   $\times \hspace{-1pt}\approx\hspace{-1pt}\checked$  \\
\dotfill $\square$\,$\square$\,$\square$ & \dotfill $\square$\,$\square$\,$\square$\\
\dotfill $\square$\,$\square$\,$\square$ & \dotfill $\square$\,$\square$\,$\square$\\
\dotfill $\square$\,$\square$\,$\square$ & \dotfill $\square$\,$\square$\,$\square$
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Let me check your code. I need the lines to be compact...

Comment: There should be no separator in the first line (the grey one).

Comment: @Colas, now i remove vertical line in gray row.